# Understanding Tukey's test results for a one-factor ANOVA

Tags: statistics, variance, means

I performed ANOVA on a set of data which includes 6 groups (called 101-106), each group has between 6 and 8 observations, and all values are negative. I used python for that task and got `p value < 0.05` which tells me that the group's means are not equal. Now I would like to know which group is different from which. Therefore I used Tukey's test (with python) which resulted in the following summary table:

```
    group1  group2  meandiff    lower   upper   reject
0   101     102     0.2917    -0.0425   0.6259  False
1   101     103     0.1571    -0.1649   0.4792  False
2   101     104     -0.1333   -0.4675   0.2009  False
3   101     105     0.0833    -0.2509   0.4175  False
4   101     106     -0.0500   -0.3626   0.2626  False
5   102     103     -0.1345   -0.4566   0.1875  False
6   102     104     -0.4250   -0.7592  -0.0908  True
7   102     105     -0.2083   -0.5425   0.1259  False
8   102     106     -0.3417   -0.6543  -0.0290  True
9   103     104     -0.2905   -0.6125   0.0316  False
10  103     105     -0.0738   -0.3959   0.2482  False
11  103     106     -0.2071   -0.5067   0.0924  False
12  104     105     0.2167    -0.1175   0.5509  False
13  104     106     0.0833    -0.2293   0.3960  False
14  105     106     -0.1333   -0.4460   0.1793  False
```

If the `reject` column says `True` we reject the null hypothesis and the means are NOT equal, if the `reject` column says `False` we accept the null hypothesis and the means are equal. As you can see, the result is a bit weird, for example group 101 is not different from the other groups, which cannot be true since it most be different from at least 1 group according to the ANOVA result. Also, group 102 and 104 are different, but they are both similar to group 103 which does not make any sense. Am I missing something?
I used this method (and syntax) in the past and it worked fine.

Groups:

101: -1.45, -1.35,  -1.6,   -1.6,   -1.65,  -1.65

102: -1.5,  -1.4,   -1.15,  -1.1,   -1.25,  -1.15

103: -1.5,  -1.6,   -1.525, -1.125, -1.2,   -1.5,   -1.3

104: -1.9,  -1.55,  -1.55,  -1.7,   -1.95,  -1.45

105: -1.55, -1.65,  -1.5,   -1.3,   -1.3,   -1.5

106: -2 -1.4    -1.8    -1.75   -1.15   -1.7    -1.45   -1.55

Comment: It would help to see group sizes, means and SDs and the ANOVA table.// Pending that info, I'll comment that Tukey's test uses a different criterion from ANOVA in declaring differences and so sometimes there are inconsistencies. However, your difficulty may be more fundamental, perhaps a programming or syntax error. // Finally, the traditional Tukey test is really only for balanced designs and you say you have different samples sizes in groups; wonder what aprox adjustment Python makes to Tukey because of that.

Comment: See edited question. I've added the observations for each group. The python script for ANOVA produce f_statistic and p_value, but I would like to focus on the Tukey's test. Let's assume that the ANOVA is currect. I used the Tukey's test syntax for similar data and it worked fine.

Comment: I hope the Minitab output in my Answer below is clearer to you than the Python output. (I believe there is no conflict between Minitab and Python results.) If confusion remains, please leave another Comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the data which I entered into Minitab, thinking it is a good
idea to compare output of what ought to be standard procedures between the
two statistical packages.

```
One-way ANOVA: G1, G2, G3, G4, G5, G6 

Method

Null hypothesis         All means are equal
Alternative hypothesis  At least one mean is different
Significance level      α = 0.05

Equal variances were assumed for the analysis.


Factor Information

Factor  Levels  Values
Factor       6  G1, G2, G3, G4, G5, G6


Analysis of Variance

Source  DF  Adj SS   Adj MS  F-Value  P-Value
Factor   5  0.7331  0.14662     4.00    0.006
Error   33  1.2096  0.03666
Total   38  1.9427


Model Summary

       S    R-sq  R-sq(adj)  R-sq(pred)
0.191457  37.73%     28.30%      14.60%
```

.

```
Means

Factor  N     Mean   StDev        95% CI
G1      6  -1.5500  0.1225  (-1.7090, -1.3910)
G2      6  -1.2583  0.1594  (-1.4174, -1.0993)
G3      7  -1.3929  0.1830  (-1.5401, -1.2456)
G4      6  -1.6833  0.2041  (-1.8424, -1.5243)
G5      6  -1.4667  0.1402  (-1.6257, -1.3076)
G6      8  -1.6000  0.2673  (-1.7377, -1.4623)

Pooled StDev = 0.191457
```

[image]

The largest differences in means are between G2 and G4 and between G2 and G6.
Because the F-test is significant at the 1% level (P-value 0.006), it reasonable
to say that at least the largest difference (btw G2 and G4) must be statistically significant. It is not fair to make many direct comparisons among the 95% CIs
in the output and figure above, because error probabilities may proliferate
in making many comparisons. However, in view of the information above it
should not be surprising the Python's Tukey procedure chooses the two largest
differences as significant.

Below is Minitab's version of the Tukey procedure.

```
Tukey Pairwise Comparisons 

Grouping Information Using the Tukey Method and 95% Confidence

Factor  N     Mean  Grouping
G2      6  -1.2583  A
G3      7  -1.3929  A B
G5      6  -1.4667  A B
G1      6  -1.5500  A B
G6      8  -1.6000    B
G4      6  -1.6833    B

Means that do not share a letter are significantly different.
```

[image]

Thus we see that the Tukey procedure chooses exactly the two largest
differences among pairs of group sample means as significant with 
a 'family' significance level of 5%. The Python and Minitab outputs
are not in conflict.

I think it is possible that your confusion may have arisen from looking
at differences among means instead of the group means themselves. Furthermore, if you
are going to look at differences among means, you have to consider *absolute*
rather than *signed* differences. The biggest absolute differences are
declared significant by both Python and Minitab.

Comment: Wow, Thank you! this is a great and detailed answer!